# How do I delete the "Recent Items"?

Tags: dashboard

The "Recent Items" list covers some of the buttons in CiviCRM.  How can I empty the list of "Recent Items"?

Comment: Do you mean the recent item block that tracks your Civi movements?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: What platform do you have your CiviCRM installed from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric, if you are using Drupal, "Recent Items" are contained in a block.  You can disable the block and it will no longer display.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Drupal and have now set the 'CiviCRM Recent Items' block to show only on 'civicrm/dashboard'  and 'civicrm/user'.  This removed it from the custom data sets and fields but preserves it on the dashboard. Just what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Though this question is pretty old, MillerTech recently developed [this extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/millertech-clear-recent-items) to add a button on the Drupal Recent Items block to clear the list. Hope this will be useful cheers! 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply logout and log back in.

Just tested on demo - http://d46.demo.civicrm.org

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. I am still bothered that the "Recent Items" list overlaps other parts of the site and that there is no way to get it out of the way without going to the trouble of logging out and loosing my place in what I am currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to see how that list is built, check out /civicrm/CRM/Utils/Recent.php. I think the quickest way to clear the list is to empty the relevant session var, like so:

```
$session = CRM_Core_Session::singleton();
$session->set('CRM_Utils_Recent', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

i have never seen the content of this list, in a Drupal Block, extend beyond the block. I don't know your CMS but it sounds like it might be a theming issue.

Comment: I think that it is not actually extending beyond the block.  Other sections are so large that they extend under the "Recent Items" block.  For example, after I pull up the list  of "Custom data" sets, the entries in the 'Recent Items' block covers the 'Preview' and 'More' buttons.  The same is true when I am working on the customs fields of a custom data set. The result is that I cannot use 'Settings', 'Disable or 'Delete' for those custom data sets or custom data fields that are hidden under the 'Recent Items list.

Comment: why not add a screenshot to your original question since we all see this sort of stuff differently. it might help someone give you the right help